# In tensorflow, why is there only one validation loss, when there are many mini-batch of validation data?

Tags: tensorflow, validation, mini-batch

In tensorflow, if we provide `validation_data` in `.fit()`, we get validation loss. But there is only one validation loss even if the validation dataset has many mini-batches. So I was wondering how tensorflow calculates the loss for validation.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(4,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(loss='MAE')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df)
data = data.map(lambda x: (x[:4], x[-1:]))
train = data.take(900).batch(10)
val = data.skip(900).batch(10)
model.fit(train, validation_data=val, epochs=50)
```

this will give:

```
Epoch 1/50
90/90 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4025 - val_loss: 0.3321
Epoch 2/50
90/90 [==============================] - 0s 635us/step - loss: 0.3114 - val_loss: 0.3065
Epoch 3/50
90/90 [==============================] - 0s 765us/step - loss: 0.2906 - val_loss: 0.2919
Epoch 4/50
90/90 [==============================] - 0s 689us/step - loss: 0.2784 - val_loss: 0.2807
Epoch 5/50
90/90 [==============================] - 0s 629us/step - loss: 0.2709 - val_loss: 0.2738
...
```

There is only one validation loss when there are 10 validation mini-batches in the validation dataset. Does tensorflow takes just one mini-batch to calculate the loss? Or does it calculate the y_pred for each batch individually, then calculate the loss for the entire validation data? Or does it calculate 10 loss for the 10 mini-batches, then take a summary statistic?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10426)

> For training loss, keras does a running average over the batches. For validation loss, a conventional average over all the batches in validation data is performed. The training accuracy is the average of the accuracy values for each batch of training data during training.

But I would take the answer with grain of salt. The code is not clear, but it seems that validation loss is just an average over the batches. You could use some synthetic data to verify that if your life is depending on it.